# Chrome Extension: How to assign global value from onMessage local scope function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Basically what I am trying to do is send a message from the popup.js by grabbing values from the input fields, and onMessage in the content_script to assign those values from that local scope to the global scope. I can't manage to do it! I can close the whole code in the onMessage function, but then to get to next function of the code I have to keep clicking save on the chrome extension. If someone knows this way better than I do with chrome extensions and what not please review my code and guide me to progress. I have been on this for like a week and my head is about to expload!

I have tried enclosing all the code in the onMessage function in the content_script. I have tried flipping which .js files are sending the message and trying to send the input fields from the extension as a response. I have tried to exclude the sendMessage out of the .click DOM function. Reviewed Messaging API on Google Chrome Extension and im puzzled.

content.js file

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener (
    function(request) {
    item_name = request.name;
    item_color = request.color;
    item_category = request.category;
    item_size = request.size;

    console.log(item_name);
    console.log(item_color);
    console.log(item_category);
    console.log(item_size);
});

var url = window.location.href;
var i;

var item_category;
var item_name;
var item_color;
var item_size;

console.log(item_name);
console.log(item_color);
console.log(item_category);
console.log(item_size);
```

popup.js file

```
document.getElementById("save_input").onclick = function() {
  var item_name_save = document.getElementById("item_name_save").value;
  var item_color_save = document.getElementById("item_color_save").value;
  var item_category_save = document.getElementById("item_category_save").value;
  var item_size_save = document.getElementById("item_size_save").value;

  chrome.storage.sync.set({'item_name_save' : item_name_save}, function() {
    console.log('Value is set to ' + item_name_save);
  });
  chrome.storage.sync.set({'item_color_save' : item_color_save}, function() {
    console.log('Value is set to ' + item_color_save);
  });
  chrome.storage.sync.set({'item_category_save' : item_category_save}, function() {
    console.log('Value is set to ' + item_category_save);
  });
  chrome.storage.sync.set({'item_size_save' : item_size_save}, function() {
    console.log('Value is set to ' + item_size_save);
  });

  const msg = { name: item_name_save,
    color: item_color_save,
    category: item_category_save,
    size: item_size_save
  };
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, msg, function() {
    });
  });

  location.reload();
  // window.close();
}
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Supreme bot",
    "description": "A bot for Supreme",
    "version": "1.0",

    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_title": "Supreme bot"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
            "js": ["bot-functionallity.js"]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
      "activeTab",
      "tabs",
      "storage",
      "tabs"
    ]
}
```

(When all code is in the onMessage function, works but not as intended)
[The Incorrect Functionality](https://i.gyazo.com/15ab2c8e6eb5b10a78df34bb0d0bfcae.gif)

I basically want the content.js to NOT be all inside of the onMessage function because that doesn't work properly, and have it assign values in the global scope from the onMessage function. I just want that info to be sent 1 time from the popup.js to the content.js.

Comment: onMessage simply registers a callback that's invoked **after** the subsequent code has run so it won't make sense to expose values globally. That's how the JavaScript event loop works.

Comment: @wOxxOm Then how can I grab input fields from the popup.js and use them globally in the content.js? The link that I posted show what the functionality is for, else I would have to hard-code those values before running the extension. The chrome messaging is the only way I could find to send inputs/data from 1 file of the extension to another.

Comment: Either 1) put everything inside onMessage and fix the code so it runs properly or 2) instead of `content_scripts` in manifest.json use chrome.tabs.executeScript twice: first one with `code` parameter to set the global values and second one with `file` to run the content script.

Comment: @wOxxOm I already tried putting everything in onMessage for like a week, so I guess I will look into chrome.tabs.executeScript

Comment: @wOxxOm Alright I got it to "work" with surrounding everything in the .addListener... but now it listens for every time the popup.html opens to run parts of the code! what do I do

Comment: @wOxxOm wow... all I had to use was chrome.storage.sync.get from the other thing i set in previous file -.- just realized how useful that can be

Answer (score 0):

I just set the value with `chrome.storage.sync.set` and use `chrome.storage.sync.get` in the other file...